# Code work in codepen/jsfiddle but not html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

That code work fine in CodePen and JSFiddle, but on html page working only buton "Delete". I load script src jquery 1.6.4 and put JS code in . What`s going on?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVwaVz

```
$("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});

function deleteRow(r)
{
var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById("table-data").deleteRow(i);
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `.live` with `.on`

Comment: This normally means that you haven't loaded jQuery in your page properly, or that you should be running your code within a document ready event handler. 1.6.4 is a very old version of jQuery - you should upgrade to at least 1.12. Ideally 3.2 if you don't need legacy IE support. Also, `live()` was deprecated a long time ago too. You should be using the delegated signature of the `on()` method instead, once you've updated jQuery. It would help us diagnose the issue if you could check the console and edit the question to include any errors you see.

Comment: @AlexSlipknot if OP is really using 1.6.4 that will cause an error as `on()` was added in 1.7

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yes. But I think on html page present several jQuery versions. Just my guess. If it's work then I'm right ))

Comment: Ok, I loaded jquery 3.2.1 and changed from live() to on(). but... still not working.

Comment: You can debug your script. Add breakpoint on line that you need to see what's happened

Comment: $("input.tr_clone_add").on('click', function() {

<- Error is some there.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function() {...`

Comment: Still nothing...